# How would one optimally use DropDownChoice in Wicket with ChoiceRenderer to handle the display and ID values?

Tags: java, wicket

I am attempting to create a simple dropdown select box in a form with Wicket and am stumped by the exception that Wicket is throwing.  As follows:

**Last cause: No get method defined for class: class java.lang.Long expression: id**

As I continue to examine the code and the Wicket documentation, I simply cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong and could use the helpful eyes of the Stackoverflow and Wicket community.  Here are some relevant code snippets... First, my form which uses a CompoundPropertyModel:

```
add(jobForm);

// Unrelated fields snipped, see 'employmentTypeId':
jobForm.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Job>(jobModel));
jobForm.add(new DropDownChoice("employmentTypeId", new List<GenericPickList>, new ChoiceRenderer<GenericPickList>("description", "id")));
```

The arguments in the DropDownChoice explained: #1, the wicket:id of the component, #2, in the actual implementation, this is a fully populated List collection of GenericPickList (i.e. List), #3, my ChoiceRenderer that identifies the description field as the display value and the id value as the ID, both from a GenericPickList class.

The GenericPickList class is simple:

```
public class GenericPickList {

    private long id;
    private String description;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

The error suggests that the ChoiceRenderer is not finding the getter for the id field in GenericPickList, but it's there so I'm led to believe my assumptions are incorrect.  Can anyone offer any insight with this?

As an added note (and point of frustration), it appears to work fine with the "id" is removed from the ChoiceRenderer constructor:

```
new ChoiceRenderer<GenericPickList>("description");
```

Of course, since these are data driven values with primary keys associated, the inclusion of the ID value is required for my purposes.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the Wicket implementation in the debugger to see how the exception comes to be? This should be fairly doable.

Comment: You're right, I'm sure that's doable.  I'll see if that uncovers anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use "id" your essentially telling wicket to look up the property id in your model and it doesnt look like the model of whatever employmentTypeId type is has the property id.

[Wicket Choice Renderer Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/ChoiceRenderer.html)

Comment: `Job` is the model for the form, the DropDownChoice has a different one. (Probably the `employmenttypes` property of `Job`)

Comment: GenericPicklistCollection("employmenttypes") actually is a LoadableDetachableModel of GenericPickList.  The "employmenttypes" String is part of the constructor.  It loads a List<GenericPickList>.  So ChoiceRenderer is actually specifying the description and id of the GenericPickList class.

Comment: @mchandler You should probably avoid using custom classes that you don't explain in your question. It would've been better to just include an anonymous `LoadableDetachableModel` that returns a dummy value. (Something like `new ArrayList<GenericPickList>()` would've sufficed.) The fact there's a form and that it uses a `CompoundPropertyModel` might for all we know be completely irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @millimoose Understood and noted for future reference. And you're correct, the use of CompoundPropertyModel in this case is irrelevant to the problem.  To your point, I'll adjust the code snippet accordingly for clarity.

Comment: @mchandler he is correct.  I'll update my answer to reflect what he is saying.

Comment: I was attempting to use an Object called GenericPickList to set a value for the employmentTypeId field on my Job class which was a long field rather than being of type GenericPickList.  Jesus's answer opened my eyes to that, so the class has been refactored to an employmentType of type GenericPickList and now everything is falling in to place.  It's how I should have done it to begin with anyway.  Thanks Jesus!